# How to make flutter imports absolute by default

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea, import

While working with flutter in android studio, by default, imports are relative; But I want all imports to be absolute by default. How can I achieve this?

Default : `../../somefile.dart`

Required : `package:project/lib/utility/somefile.dart`

Comment: Did you find a way?  This would be really helpful.  If it is not possible, do you know whether the fix would need to happen on Intellij Idea's side or Dart's?  Do you know if there is an open issue at all?

Comment: No, @atreeon. I am still clueless on how to do this. Currently, I am manually making them imports absolute by using context menu.